# How to dynamically assign datasource to listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am having a problem with dynamically assigning datasource to listview.

For example I have list of receivedBonuses(Bonus), receivedLeaves(Leave) and I want listview to display those list items depending on what link button user clicked.

Researching internet and stackoverflow.com i found 3 solutions:

1. Using repeater inside the listview. But in my case, I could not apply it to my case and i got totally confused
2. Using nested listviews. I tried to do like this:

```
       <asp:ListView ID = "bonuses" runat="server" DataSource ='<%# Eval("received_bonuses") %>' >
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>

                <td><%# Eval("bonus_desc")%></td>

                <td><%# Eval("bonus_type")%></td>                  

            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
                 <LayoutTemplate>

             <table>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Bonus Description</th> 

                        <th>Bonus Received Date</th>



                    </tr>

                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />

                        </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>
```

```
             <table>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Bonus Description</th> 

                        <th>Bonus Received Date</th>



                    </tr>

                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />

                        </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>

</asp:ListView>


    <br />
```

and on back code I tried to write like this: 

  `protected void dataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataBindChildren();`

```
    }
```

It didn't give any errors it just didn't work.

3. Using data pager

I have no idea how to apply it to my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you clean up your code? Please?

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do on the server side is change the DataSource or DataSourceID property and  call DataBind on the ListView.

You have to make sure when using <%# Eval("") %> syntax that the objects you are binding to have those properties that are named in the Eval. So you may have a problem with with switching datasources when your properties are prepended with the typename and underscore. 
That being said.  There are 2 options you have an changing a data source.  In the click event of the button or whatever switching mechanism you are using you can just write something like.

Not using a DataSource in the markup:

```
List<Bonus> bonusList = GetBonuses();
MyListView.DataSource = bonusList;
MyListView.DataBind();
```

Using a DataSource in the markup:

```
//where bonus list would be the id of the datasource in the markup
MyListView.DataSourceID= "BonusList"; 

MyListView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this dynamically? If you only have "bonuse" and "leave" can you not create two listviews and then just do display logic to visible=true/false the listview based upon the link button clicked?

Comment: I thought about that, but if I do that will listView's be in the right place, and also, making too many listview's per page is not respecting the end user  right, because page will be too heavy?

Comment: If you never databind the listview it won't render anything